# xprop: understanding set command

Tags: linux, always-on-top

I am trying to force a particular window to be always on top:

```
xprop -id 0x3800154 -set _NET_WM_STATE\(ATOM\) = _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE
```

Debian buster reports:

```
xprop: error: unsupported conversion for _NET_WM_STATE(ATOM)
```

I have read https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm45408774010480

but cannot get my head around it.

Answer (score 5):

Your command is almost correct, it should be:

```sh
xprop -f _NET_WM_STATE 32a -id 0x3800154 -set _NET_WM_STATE _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE
```

- The most notable addition is the `-f` parameter. It specifies the format of the field `_NET_WM_STATE`. If this is not given, xprop does not know how to interpret the desired property value (`_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE`).
- According to the specification you provided, `_NET_WM_STATE` is a 32bit `ATOM` value (`-f _NET_WM_STATE 32a`).
- The equals sign and `\(ATOM\)` are not required

---

A sidenote that might be useful: You can also specify multiple `STATE` values by comma-separating them, e.g.

```sh
xprop -f _NET_WM_STATE 32a -id 0x3800154 -set _NET_WM_STATE _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE,_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN
```